# Why PostgreSql does not use PK index?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

If I want to select 0.5% rows, or even 5% rows from the following table via a PK, the query planner correctly chooses to use the PK index. Here is the table:

```
create table weather as
with numbers as(
select generate_series as id from generate_series(0,1048575))
select id, 
50 + 50*sin(id) as temperature_in_f, 
50 + 50*sin(id) as humidity_in_percent
from numbers;

alter table weather
add constraint pk_weather primary key(id);

vacuum analyze weather;
```

The stats are up-to-date, and the following query does use the PK index:

```
explain analyze select sum(w.id), sum(humidity_in_percent), count(*) 
from weather as w
where w.id between 1 and 66720;
```

Suppose, however, that we need to join this table with another, much smaller, one:

```
create table lightnings 
as
select id as weather_id
from weather
where humidity_in_percent between 99.99 and 100;

alter table lightnings
add constraint pk_lightnings
primary key(weather_id);

analyze lightnings;
```

Here is my join, in four logically equivalent forms:

```
explain analyze select sum(w.id), count(*) from weather as w
where w.humidity_in_percent between 99.99 and 100
and exists(select * from lightnings as l
  where l.weather_id=w.id);

explain analyze select sum(w.id), count(*) 
from weather as w
join lightnings as l
  on l.weather_id=w.id
where w.humidity_in_percent between 99.99 and 100;

explain analyze select sum(w.id), count(*) 
from lightnings as l
join weather as w
  on l.weather_id=w.id
where w.humidity_in_percent between 99.99 and 100;

-- replaced explicit join with where clause
explain analyze select sum(w.id), count(*) 
from lightnings as l, weather as w
where w.humidity_in_percent between 99.99 and 100
and l.weather_id=w.id;
```

Unfortunately the query planner resorts to scanning the whole weather table:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=22645.68..22645.69 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=167.427..167.427 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=180.12..22645.52 rows=32 width=4) (actual time=2.500..166.444 rows=6672 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (w.id = l.weather_id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on weather w  (cost=0.00..22407.64 rows=5106 width=4) (actual time=0.013..158.593 rows=6672 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((humidity_in_percent >= 99.99::double precision) AND (humidity_in_percent <= 100::double precision))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1041904"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=96.72..96.72 rows=6672 width=4) (actual time=2.479..2.479 rows=6672 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 235kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on lightnings l  (cost=0.00..96.72 rows=6672 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.908 rows=6672 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.326 ms"
"Execution time: 167.581 ms"
```

The query planner's estimate on how many rows in weather table will be selected is rows=5106. This is more or less close to the exact value of 6672. If I select this small number of rows in weather table via id, the PK index is used. If I select the same amount via a join with another table, the query planner goes for scanning the table.

What am I missing?

```
select version()
"PostgreSQL 9.4.0"
```

Edit: if I remove the condition on humidity, the query planner correctly recognizes that the condition on weather.id is quite selective, and chooses to use the index on PK:

```
explain analyze select sum(w.id), count(*) from weather as w
where exists(select * from lightnings as l
  where l.weather_id=w.id);
"Aggregate  (cost=14677.84..14677.85 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=37.200..37.200 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..14644.48 rows=6672 width=4) (actual time=0.022..36.189 rows=6672 loops=1)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on lightnings l  (cost=0.00..96.72 rows=6672 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.868 rows=6672 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using pk_weather on weather w  (cost=0.42..2.17 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=6672)"
"              Index Cond: (id = l.weather_id)"
"              Heap Fetches: 0"
"Planning time: 0.321 ms"
"Execution time: 37.254 ms"
```

Yet adding a condition totally confuses the query planner.

Comment: Could you show us your configuration file? Especially random_page_cost, this has a huge impact on sequential read vs. index scan

Comment: I made sure set random_page_cost=4; - no difference whatsoever.

Comment: A lower value for random_page_cost does benefit an index scan, your primary key. set random_page_cost to 2.6; gives me an index scan on all query examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecting the optimiser to use an index on the PK of the larger table implies that you expect the query to be driven from the smaller table. Of course, you know that the rows that the smaller table will join to in the larger one are the same as those selected by the predicate on it, but the optimiser does not.

Look at the line on the plan:

```
Hash Join  (cost=180.12..22645.52 rows=32 width=4) (actual time=2.500..166.444 rows=6672 loops=1)"
```

It expects 32 rows to result from the join, but 6672 actually result.

Anyway, it pretty much has the option of:

1. A full scan on the smaller table, and an index lookup on the larger, with the predicate being used to filter out rows subsequent to the join (and expecting most of the rows to then be filtered out).
2. A full scan on both tables, with rows being removed by the predicate on the larger table, and a hash join of the result.
3. A scan of the larger table with rows being removed by the predicate, and an index lookup on the smaller table that may fail to find a value.

The second of these has been judged to be the lowest cost, and I think it is correct to do so based on the evidence it has, as hash joins are very efficient for joining many rows.

Of course it would probably be more efficient to place an index on weather(humidity_in_percent,id) in this particular case, but I suspect that this is a modified version of your real situation (the sum of the id column?) so specific advice may not be applicable.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the explanation. This is very strange. The weather table has 1M rows, and the QP knows it. The QP expects only 32 rows - why not use the index on PK to retrieve those 32 rows?

Comment: It believes that it still has to retrieve 6,000-ish rows of the table data via an index and then apply a filter to the rows when they are retrieved, regardless of whether all but 32 are then discarded. This kind of situation can be tricky for query optimisation, as working out whether to drive the query from the smaller lighting table, or the filtered weather table, can be critical. The cardinality of the join is also tricky to calculate, particularly when the required data sets from the two tables are correlated -- the optimiser does not know that.

Comment: Yes, "this is a modified version of my real situation" - and also simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the differences your seeing between the first query, which uses the index and the other 3 which don't, is in the where clause.

In the first query, your where clause is on w.id, which is indexed.

In the other 3, the effective where clause is on w.humidity_in_percent. I tested the following ...

```
create index wh_idx on weather(humidity_in_percent);

explain analyse select sum(w.id), count(*) from weather as w
where w.humidity_in_percent between 99.99 and 100
and exists(select * from lightnings as l
  where l.weather_id=w.id);
```

and get a much better plan. I tried to post the actual plan returned, but I'm having trouble formatting it for proper display, sorry.

Comment: Yes, adding an index on humidity does help. My question is why a useful index on id is not used.

Comment: Again, my hunch is that your not using an index because your where clause is not on w.id ( the index ), but is on w.humidity_in_percent (non-indexed). I only added the index to test my assertion. If you want to use an index, you need to put on on the fields in your search.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by "your where clause is not on w.id" - IMO the EXISTS condition is a part of the WHERE clause, and it is definitely on w.id column.

Comment: The EXISTS in the query above is your way of joining. It contains select * in its use of w.id, right? It's included in the where clause, but you're asking for everything with it. Try running explain analyse on just your exists.  

    explain analyse select * from lightnings as l, weather as w where l.weather_id=w.id;  

And you'll see what I mean. Almost always, when the Pg QP isn't doing what you think it should, it's because you're not doing what you think you are.

Comment: I replaced an explicit join with a condition on where clause, adding a fourth logically equivalent query. No difference. –

Comment: Post example please.  
In all cases, I think you're missing the fundamental thing here.  The column your using to reduce your result set is humidity_in_percent, not weather.id. To use an index for result set reduction, it MUST be on the field by which your trying to reduce, in this case humidity_in_percent. QP will not use an index on an unrelated field, and w.id is not related to the reduction process.

Comment: I did post a fourth example. I think I am using both id and humidity to filter rows. If there is no condition on humidity, the QP does filter on id.